# How to build an app using a serverless architecture?

Tags: rest, backend, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm confused about Firebase and serverless in general, as I was just introduced to this concept recently (note that I'm still studying computer science and I'm just exploring on my own now).

In the past I've been part of a project that had the following structure:

- Front End in a Single-page-app
- Back End built as a REST API

Now let's say I want to build a product, that might have a website and mobile apps. It also has to have backend logic as there are accounts, objects owned by users, and possible integration with a payment service.

What I initially expected from this, before knowning about serverless, is that you build a backend using something like Go (was my case), where you handle all the database data and third-party integrations, build a front end with something like Vue, and then use the backend's REST API to communicate between both of them.

Is this still the case with serverless? Do you build the whole backend server code, or does it work in another way?

I don't need/want you to explain all of it to me. I just need some insight on what is done and common so I can investigate further.